# Subquery, Nested Select, Join, something else? - not sure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

When I try limiting my results, I limit them too much.

```
Select Distinct Agreements.AgrmntID, Agreements.Status, JobSites.SiteName,
  AgreementCharges.TotalSaleAmt, AgreementCharges.PartID,
  AgreementSchedules.FormanEmpID, LaborCodeTypes.RepairCode
From Agreements Inner Join
  AgreementCharges On Agreements.AgrmntID = AgreementCharges.AgrmntID Inner Join
  JobSites On JobSites.CustSiteID = Agreements.CustSiteID Left Outer Join
  AgreementSchedules On Agreements.AgrmntID = AgreementSchedules.AgrmntID
  Left Outer Join
  LaborCodeTypes On LaborCodeTypes.RepairID = AgreementSchedules.RepairID
Where Agreements.Status = 2 And AgreementCharges.PartID = 31 And
  LaborCodeTypes.RepairCode = '04 - LS'
```

If there is no RepairCode matching '04 - LS' I still need the AgrmntID and TotalSaleAmt.  Likewise, if there is no AgreementSchedule at all, I need AgrmntID and TotalSaleAmt.

Output:

```
AgrmntID  Status  SiteName  TotalSaleAmt  PartID  FormanEmpID  RepairCode
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2         2       TEST01    $100.00       31      66           04 - LS
2         2       TEST03    $300.00       31      21           04 - LS
```

Expected Output:

```
AgrmntID  Status  SiteName  TotalSaleAmt  PartID  FormanEmpID  RepairCode
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2         2       TEST01    $100.00       31      66           04 - LS
2         2       TEST02    $200.00       31
2         2       TEST03    $300.00       31      21           04 - LS
```

I've looked and looked and am now coming here for help.  Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working:

```
Select Distinct Agreements.AgrmntID, Agreements.Status, JobSites.SiteName,
  AgreementCharges.TotalSaleAmt, AgreementCharges.PartID, a.FormanEmpID,
  a.RepairCode
From Agreements Inner Join
  JobSites On JobSites.CustSiteID = Agreements.CustSiteID Left Join
  AgreementCharges On Agreements.AgrmntID = AgreementCharges.AgrmntID Left Join
  (Select AgreementSchedules.AgrmntID, AgreementSchedules.FormanEmpID,
      b.RepairCode
    From AgreementSchedules Inner Join
      (Select LaborCodeTypes.RepairCode, LaborCodeTypes.RepairID
        From LaborCodeTypes) b On AgreementSchedules.RepairID = b.RepairID
    Where b.RepairCode = '04 - LS') a On Agreements.AgrmntID = a.AgrmntID
Where Agreements.Status = 2 And AgreementCharges.PartID = 31
```

Thank you very much pkuderov, your response kept pointing me in the right direction.  And think you kiwirichard, even though you deleted your response.

Answer (score 0):

my version:

```
Select Distinct 
    Agreements.AgrmntID, 
    Agreements.Status, 
    JobSites.SiteName,
    AgreementCharges.TotalSaleAmt, 
    AgreementCharges.PartID,
    AgreementSchedules.FormanEmpID, 
    LaborCodeTypes.RepairCode
From Agreements
Inner Join JobSites On 
    JobSites.CustSiteID = Agreements.CustSiteID
Left Join AgreementCharges On 
    Agreements.AgrmntID = AgreementCharges.AgrmntID 
Left Join AgreementSchedules On 
    Agreements.AgrmntID = AgreementSchedules.AgrmntID
Left Join LaborCodeTypes On 
    LaborCodeTypes.RepairID = AgreementSchedules.RepairID
Where 
    Agreements.Status = 2 
    AND AgreementCharges.PartID = 31
    AND coalesce(LaborCodeTypes.RepairCode, '04 - LS') = '04 - LS'
```

P.S. next time format your query better if you're going to show it to others :)

Comment: haha - thanks... the program I use constantly reformats what I type - I'll try to make it nicer in the future!!  This worked well and included the NULL LaborCodeType but skipped the ones that had neither NULL nor '04 - LS'.  In those cases, an AgreementSchedule with LaborCodeTypes.RepairID = 'Vendor Bill' was created without '04 - LS'... is there a way to include those when they match with PartID = 31??

Comment: stop-stop-stop:) I think I just lose your point of view on what you want so let's do it step by step. For this just remove the last 2 left joins and conditions respected to it in `where` clause and look at result (without 2 last columns). Ask yourself - is it what you want? If yes then add `left join AgreementSchedules ...` and ask yourself again. If no then we need to understand which conditions should be added.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer…  I did what you suggested and everything works, it’s just omitting a few entries.  I Edited your answer so hopefully you can understand and help me figure this out!!

Comment: @JamieS, sorry hadn't been here for a long time(( and it's great that you found an answer by yourself

Comment: Thank you for your help!!  ...and sorry I didn't properly format my answer ;)